# Asymptotic distribution of a specific ML estimator

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics

Consider a random independent sample of size $n$ from a distribution defined by the following probability density function$$f(x)=\frac{3}{4\theta}\cdot\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\theta ^2}\right)$$ when $-\theta<x<\theta$, zero otherwise. The value of $\theta$ which maximizes$$\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{X_i^2}{\theta^2}\right)-n\cdot \ln(\theta)$$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$. I would like to get an approximation to its asymptotic (i.e. in the $n\rightarrow \infty$  limit) distribution.

Differentiating the previous expression with respect to $\theta$ and making the answer equal to zero yields the so called normal equation; the ML estimator is a unique (positive) solution to this equation. By linearizing it (hopefully legitimate under the circumstances), one gets the following approximation for the ML estimator$$\theta+\theta\cdot\frac{-\frac{n}{2}+\sum\frac{Y_i^2}{1-Y_i^2}}{2\sum\frac{Y_i^2}{(1-Y_i^2)^2}}$$ where $Y_i$ are values of a random sample from the original distribution with $\theta=1$. Note that the numerator has the expected value of $0$ but an infinite variance; the denominator has both of these infinite. This is what makes this problem so challenging (finite values would make it trivial).

So far I have managed to explore the last distribution only numerically; for the ratio itself (when $n=1000$) I get[image] a PDF of a somehow double-exponential shape, but any attempt for an analytical description escapes me.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: I teach a Mathematical-Statistics course and I have chosen this example (rather randomly, among others) to demonstrate to students how does one find the method-of-moment estimator (no problem here, including asymptotic distribution) and the ML estimator - no problem finding it numerically when using a computer, but so far impossible to prove more than its consistency.